# How to multiply matrix element by scalar in R

Tags: r

I am struggling to do this simple multiplication, I want to multiply matrix element with constant :

```
mydata <- read.csv("c:/mydata.csv",header=F,dec=",")
5*mydata[1,3]
```

I am getting following error :

```
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(mydata[1, 3], 0.1) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
```

Whats wrong with the code?

Comment: How did you create `mydata`?

Comment: I imported it using read.csv

Comment: mydata<-read.csv("c:/mydata.csv",header=F,dec=",")

Comment: you are trying to multiply a scalar to a factor, thats why the error. Check 3rd column in your data.

Comment: @Amrita Thanks. Is there any way to convert it to numeric matrix ?

Comment: Try adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.csv()` then try it again.  Otherwise please show a few lines of the top of the file

Comment: we cannot help much without looking at your data and without knowing what result you want to get . You can try 5 * as.numeric(mydata[1,3]) and see if this is what you need.

Comment: @Richard : Thanks. But now i am getting error as : **Error in 5 * mydata[1, 3] : non-numeric argument to binary operator**

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506691/converting-from-a-list-to-numeric-in-r <-- This thread was helpful. I used data.matrix(mydata).

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a header in that file?

Comment: @ ekstroem : yes, it doesnt have header